# SQL to create login, user, database, schema, table

Tags: sql-server

I need a T-SQL query to create

1. login - with name and password, say "John" with "12345"
2. user, say "DbUser101"
3. schema, say "JohnSchema"
4. database, say "JohnDatabase"
5. table, "JohnTable"

I will execute it in SSMS as `sa`, but I want that the database, schema, table to look like created by John in SSMS, as if John logged in SSMS and created table etc.

This means database owned by John and having as user `DbUSer101`, it means that John has all the necessary permissions to create, read, write, modify the table but no more than that. I also want that the user to have the default schema `JohnSchema`.

I know it sounds simple and for each step is easy to find the T-SQL to do it but the problem appears when put everything together. For example, when you create the user, either you created it after login creation but then the table is not associated with that user or if you do it later an error tells you that

> The login already has an account under a different user name

Comment: Step 1.  Install SQL Server Express.  You automatically get the sa user as you are setting up the database using that admin account and you will be required to provide that user a password.  Step 2.  Lookup how to create a database and then create a Database called JohnDatabase.  Step 3.  Look up how to create a schema.  The default schema is dbo and you can immediately begin adding database objects to that schema such as a table.  Step 4. Look up how to create a table and create a table called JohnDatabase.  Step 5.  Create a standard user and apply user permissions to that user giving access

Answer (score 1):

SQLServer logins, users, schemas have confused a lot of people getting started with SQLServer. It's probably worth taking a step back to understand SQLServer's model.

You can create a database and then change it's owner...

```
create database johndb;
alter authorization on database::jdb to john;
```

When you do this it's good to note a few things...

- Remember, john is a login, not a user.
- Logins exist at the server level and can own databases.
- Users exist within databases and cannot own databases at the server level.
- Every database, when it is created, has a user dbo (and a schema dbo)
- The built-in user dbo represents the 'database owner' in each database.
- Logins, like john are mapped to database users when they use a database.

The key awkward point comes when you transfer ownership of the database to the Login john. At that point SQLServer automatically maps Login john to the dbo user in the database and makes dbo his default schema.

You can then create a schema for john, if you don't want to use dbo schema. And you can create tables that belong to this schema.

- The tables belong to the schema not the user or the login.
- The schema belongs to a user within the database, in this case dbo.
- This database user can be mapped to a login and to a Windows principal.

Adding the schema and a table the overall example would be:

```
-- submit first as separate command.
create database johndb; 

-- submit next
alter authorization on database::jdb to john;
use johndb;

-- submit as separate command, create schema must be first command.
create schema johnschema;

-- Next Command
create table johnschema.johntable ( 
    id int, 
    title varchar(21)
);
```

This does not create another user 'john' within the database. Just relies on dbo which is mapped to the john login.

This is a pretty common style, and it avoids the need to fiddle user definitions within the database if ownership of the database ever changes.

**But I Don't Want To Use the dbo User!**

If you really want login john to be the database owner, but you don't want login john to be mapped to the dbo user, you are going against the way SQLServer wants to do things.

The documented way to change database owner includes mapping the new owner's login to the dbo user.

If this is more of an XY Problem where you want something different like having an actual human user connect as a less privileged user or role, that's do-able. But then that user's login should not actually be database owner.

It's probably best to step back and decide how important it is to make SQLServer conform to your model and whether it might work better, less work, less future maintenance, to fit in with SQLServer's model.

Comment: One point here is that I want to use a different default schema name, hence the user. I have tried the code snippet and 'create user john;' triggers "'john' is not a valid login or you do not have permission." although I have done it as sa. If I add john login, then I have another error, on alter authorization: "The proposed new database owner is already a user or aliased in the database."

Comment: @Gigi code I originally posted was only working for me because of a special case, a login with sysadmin role. I removed it and adjusted the answer to include example of producing a schema and table....which might not have been as clear before.

Comment: I noticed that schema created this way is not listed with SELECT * FROM sys.schemas;

Comment: Another thing, I thought the way you set default schema is "alter user johnusr with default_schema = johnsch" so you need an user

Comment: @Gigi yes, you can't alter user dbo's default schema, so far as I can tell. If you want a different default schema, you need a user. But that user cannot be the db owner. I don't know your use scenarios or requirements. In my experience I almost never want applications to connect as the db owner, only as a less privileged user. And for application code and sp code I never want to rely on the default schema. But for casual queries by humans, it's nice to be able to.